# gtest linking error in VS2015: unresolved externals for functions defined in cpp file

Tags: c++, linker-errors, googletest

I have created a sample project in VS2015, having one header file and one cpp file. Content of my files are:

Header.h

```
int fun2(int a);
```

Source.cpp

```
#include "Header.h"

void main()
{
 fun()2;
}
int fun2(int a) {
  return ++a;
}
```

Steps followed:

1. Download Google test (gtest-1.7.0)
2. Compile gtest into a static library
3. Create a unit test project
4. Make a test case

The above setup is working fine and able to test the function, if defined in header file of given project. But if the function is defined in Source.cpp file, as written above then compilation is failing with the below linking errors:

```
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol "int __cdecl fun2(int)" (?fun2@@YAHH@Z) referenced in function "private: virtual void __thiscall a_b_Test::TestBody(void)" (?TestBody@a_b_Test@@EAEXXZ)  

Error   LNK1120 1 unresolved externals
```

Please let me know how resolve this error or how to do the unit testing of a function defined in cpp file using gtest?
I have followed the steps given on this [link](http://www.bogotobogo.com/cplusplus/google_unit_test_gtest.php).